# My SQL server start error unknown variable 'ndb-blob-read-batch-bytes=65536'

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to start a mySQL server, and i get the following error:

```
FROM C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\Data\account.err:
    2014-11-14 17:40:10    [Note]  Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
    2014-11-14 17:40:10    InnoDB:  The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
    2014-11-14 17:40:10    InnoDB:  Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
    2014-11-14 17:40:10    InnoDB:  Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
    2014-11-14 17:40:10    InnoDB:  Initializing buffer pool, size = 203.0M
    2014-11-14 17:40:10    InnoDB:  Completed initialization of buffer pool
    2014-11-14 17:40:10    InnoDB:  highest supported file format is Barracuda.
    2014-11-14 17:40:11    InnoDB:  Waiting for the background threads to start
    2014-11-14 17:40:12    InnoDB:  5.5.40 started; log sequence number 40340542
    2014-11-14 17:40:12    [ERROR]  C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld: unknown variable 'ndb-blob-read-batch-bytes=65536'
    2014-11-14 17:40:12    [ERROR]  Aborting
    2014-11-14 17:40:12    InnoDB:  Starting shutdown...
    2014-11-14 17:40:13    InnoDB:  Shutdown completed; log sequence number 40340542
    2014-11-14 17:40:13    [Note]  C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld: Shutdown complete
2014-11-14 17:40:14 - Checking server status...
2014-11-14 17:40:14 - Trying to connect to MySQL...
2014-11-14 17:40:14 - Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061) (2003)
```

Please help me to get over this...... Thanks in advance....  :)

Answer (score 0):

read the error.  it clearly tells you where the problem is in your config

```
2014-11-14 17:40:12 [ERROR] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld: unknown variable 'ndb-blob-read-batch-bytes=65536'
```

Comment: According to: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-cluster-program-options-mysqld.html#option_mysqld_ndb-blob-read-batch-bytes the range of "ndb-blob-read-batch-bytes" is 0 - 4294967295 ... so I don't get it, and if i modify the value, it just gives me the same error with the new value ...

Comment: according to your error msg you are running 5.5, "FROM C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\Data\account.err:"

Comment: your problem is not the value, it's that you are trying to use a nonexistent (in v5.5) config variable.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-cluster-program-options-mysqld.html ... same thing, i just copied the wrong link

Comment: Are you running Mysql Cluster NDB v7.2 ?  because that's the subset of the docs you are reading from...